# getnewaddress vs. getrawchangeaddress

Tags: raw-transaction

I'm using the Golang btcsuite/btcd library to write a Bitcoin app that creates custom `OP_RETURN` TXs in the blockchain.

I understand Bitcoin at a high-level (proof-of-work consensus, Merkle trees, membership, signatures, etc.), but I'm getting lost in the (unnecessarily?) complicated details of its RPC interface.

I was writing code in Go for creating a custom transaction with 1 input and 2 outputs (an OP_RETURN output and a change output). Here are my questions:

1. Is this considered a *raw* transaction? (If so, what exactly constitutes a raw transaction? Is it all transactions that don't get created via the `sendfrom/sendmany/sendtoaddress` RPC?)
2. What's the difference between `getnewaddress` and `getrawchangeaddress` at a semantic level? It seems that both generate a key-pair, but why is there a need for two different calls?
3. If I'm creating a *raw* transaction as described above, should I send the change to a `getnewaddress` key or a `getrawchangeaddress` key?

Thank you,
Alin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The **rawtransaction** interface accepts and returns "raw" hex encoded p2p compatible transactions. Using the non-rawtransaction methods (like `sendtoaddres`, will not give you the possibility to inspect or alter the created bytearray.
2. The **`getrawchangeaddress`** method will retrieve a key from the keypool and return its pubkey (encoded into an p2pkh address). Unlike **`getrawchangeaddress`**, **`gewnewaddress`** will create an address book entry that will allow you better ways to inspect/distinct what funds you have received with that address and therefore increases the chance of a reused address.
3. You should use **`getrawchangeaddress`** if you like to use the given address as a change output for your rawtransaction.

Comment: Thank you! Cool, so when people talk about a raw transaction they mean any custom-built transaction, as opposed to a fixed kind as suggested by APIs like [this one](https://godoc.org/github.com/btcsuite/btcrpcclient#Client.CreateRawTransaction). Did you mean to write "unlike" instead of "unless then"?

Comment: **Question:** If I use `getrawchangeaddress` to send the change, the change UTXO of the raw `OP_RETURN` TX I created doesn't show up in my `listunspent` query. Why is that? I would like to continue spending that change, by easily finding the UTXO for it. Should I use `getnewaddress` instead? Is there something wrong with that? This is where I am confused about the two.

Comment: (This is in _regtest_ mode and I've generated a new block for the raw TX, plus another 10 blocks after it.)

Comment: _Answer:_ Actually, I just realized the raw TX was not being included in a block because I set the transaction's fee to zero. I was able to mine it in a block and send the change to a `getnewaddress` PK. I am seeing the change in `listunspent` now. _Will check if_ `getrawchangeaddress` _works as well..._

Comment: Both `getnewaddress` and `getrawchangeaddress` work except `getnewaddress` can associate the PK with an 'account.' However, since accounts are deprecated, I will stay away from them. **Still unclear why both calls exist, especially if accounts are being deprecated:** the corresponding SK needs to be added to the wallet by both of them, so what's the difference between them?